# Why does Template Morsels not seem to work?

Tags: solspace

Template Morsels works (incredibly well) when I manually cache via its CP panel, but then after the scheduled 5 minutes passes the page takes as long to display as it would without Template Morsels. Am I misunderstanding how it works?

Edit--I set interval to 0 and now the cache sticks. Will have to see if editing or adding entries refreshes cache. Preferences is set up for this so fingers crossed.

Edit Again--Tried adding an entry and it works but, wow, every time you click the publish button it takes as long to publish as it would to load the front end page without Template Morsels. I get why this is, but that kind of makes it unworkable.

Answer (score 1):

Template morsels needs to run the entire template to be able to cache it at some point. When the cache expires, after 5 minutes as you had it set before, it must load the template in order for it to re-cache. The same thing has to happen on publish due to it changing data.

You could run a cron-job at the set intervals so it would lessen the chance that it happens on the front end.

> I get why this is, but that kind of makes it unworkable.

If it didn't do this, then your data in the morsel wouldn't be updated after you published a new entry. Why is it unworkable? Is publish speed a major concern of the end client?

Most heavy data work with EE add-ons tends to happen on publish because thats when new data is introduced and its the most expected place for longer processing to happen.

Comment: I apologize for using "unworkable" which is pretty harsh. I'm new to caching. So, could I have cron refresh the cache at a specific time so that when the page is first visited after refresh the page quickly loads the cache? Every week the client enters dozens upon dozens of new events into Calendar which accumulates over the weeks. Without caching, page loads near 30 seconds. With caching, 2 seconds. The calendar also implements ajax filtering via segments, so this results in about a dozen caches per month. Still exploring Template Morsels. Any tips would be appreciated.